# Can a CIWS engage aerial targets?

Tags: military, radar

Can a Phalanx-type Close-In Weapons System (CIWS) engage small aerial targets like drones, UAVs, rotorcraft? Is there any case that Phalanx was used against aerial targets?

Comment: What else is it supposed to do? It sure isn't anti personale or anti tank, right?

Answer (score 3):

Considering [that these systems are tested against drones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phalanx_CIWS#Incidents), then the answer is yes. The limitations on what is too small to engage for any particular system are likely classified.

Comment: I'd love to know how they avoid shooting down every passing bird.

Comment: There might just be a human involved, @RobinBennett. Someone monitoring a video feed to ensure that it doesn't trigger on a flock of birds. Or, it may be up to de-noising algorithms to pick them out.

Comment: Or, maybe that’s how they feed the crew. JK. There is probably redundancy built into the system. For instance, the system is only active when underway, away from any friendly shoreline. Once active, the system can tell the difference between something natural and something man-made by its size, speed and pattern of flight.

Comment: It should be noted that the drones of the eighties were of a different size from what we think of as drones now.

Comment: It is designed to defend against incoming missiles.  A slow moving drone would be like shooting fish in a barrel.

Comment: I wonder if DJI Phantom (the only drone I know by name, so not advertizing here :) has enough RCS to be detected and targeted by Phalanx?

Answer (score 3):

Phalanx can track and destroy missile size and speed targets, so as long as the drone or UAV has sufficient radar cross section, there would be no reason why Palanx would be unable to engage them.

The feasibility and utility of Phalanx, and similar systems against small drones and such is limited however. Imagine the risk of collateral damage if they were used in or near populated areas. There is a reason this is mainly a naval weapon...

At high seas, in turn, small drones, UAV's and rotorcrafts are not that much of a threat due to their limited range.